# Invalid syntax in while loop

Tags: python

```
cat = True
while cat = True:
    print("cat")
else:
    print("Kitten")
```

I tried to run this program but it says invalid syntax for the while loop.I don't know what to do and I can't find the answer on the internet.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberrry Pi SE. This very general Python question is not really a question for Raspberry Pi SE. See [Tour] for more information. Re your question: there is no while...else in Python, and for a comparison you need `==`. I suggest you have a look online at one of the many Python tutorials.

Comment: while ... else is actually valid !

Answer (score 3):

You've used the assignment operator `=` when testing for `True`. You should be using the comparison operator `==` to compare `cat` and `True`.

```
cat = True
while cat = True:
   print("cat")
else:
   print("Kitten")
```

The above code will output:

> ```
> while cat = True:
>           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Whereas:

```
cat = True
while cat == True:
   print("cat")
else:
   print("Kitten")
```

Will give the result you are probably expecting:

> ```
> cat
> cat
> cat
> ...
> ```

Comment: `while cat:` would be better code (but the code is nonsense), and the  question is not directly related to the Raspberry Pi